# VBA Code to work across multiple sheets in same worksheet, copy and paste

Tags: vba

I have a code: it works perfectly but am hoping to run it on sheet2 as well is there a was possible for it to work across two sheets to paste the required data in sheet3?

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.AdvancedFilter _

    Action:=xlFilterCopy, _

    CriteriaRange:=Range("J1:J2"), _

    CopyToRange:=Range("A1:G1")
```

End Sub

Comment: Just edit the code, ie, CopyToRange:=sheet2.Range("A1:G1"), and so on, then you are free to copy any other worksheets as you wish

Comment: Like Kin Siang says, just use the same code again and change the sheet name and ranges as required. Or do you want to join/add the 2 sheet's values etc?

Comment: I've edited the "CopytoRange" but it overwrite the data from sheet1, how do i get this to copy both Sheet1 & Sheet2 into Sheet3 without overwriting the data e.g. if there a 10 rows in Sheet1 and 3 rows in Sheet2. Sheet3 will have the 13 Rows copied based on Criteria in cell J2? or maybe i wasn't doing it right?